# Database Context - Refresh (RefreshMode.KeepChanges);

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a sample application to demo Linq error `Row not found or changed`

Database records looks like this -

[image]

From my application, I want to update employees with location from 'London' to 'Paris'. Here is my code -

```
var dbContext = new EmployeeDataContext();

var employeesInLondon = from emp in dbContext.Employees
                        where emp.Location.Equals("London")
                        select emp;

foreach (var employeeInLondon in employeesInLondon)
{
    employeeInLondon.Location = "Paris";
}

//Simulate as if another user is updating the database before you submit the update
Console.WriteLine("Now update the Employee table by running this in SQL Server Management Studio:");
Console.WriteLine("UPDATE Employee SET Location = 'Delhi', LastName = 'John' WHERE Location = 'London';");
Console.WriteLine("And hit any key...");
Console.ReadKey();

dbContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges); //Why the error is thrown even after adding this statement      

dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

As you can see in above code - I run a different Update SQL through SSMS, just before submitting my changes. And the error is thrown as expected.

So, I added below code just before calling `SubmitChanges()` -

```
dbContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
```

**My question is why error is still thrown even if I refresh database context before calling `SubmitChanges()`. I am still getting ChangeConflictException with above code.**

please guide what I am missing here?

FYI,
I have used below link to create above demo and I know how to add catch block to list out the conflicting object/members - 
[Row not found or changed - Finding the culprit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/09/07/system-data-linq-changeconflictexception-row-not-found-or-changed-finding-the-culprit/#commentmessage)

Comment: @Eldho this is not entity framework, this is linq-to-sql (about your retagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a conflict exception you need to resolve it... even if you refresh while keeping the modifications, there's still a non-resolved conflict when you submit your changes.

Refreshing the context will do if you update it (so there are no conflicts), not if you keep the changes.

If you want to keep your changes, try doing something like this:

```
try
{
   // the parameter tells it go ahead and update all non-conflicting items
   // afterwards it'll throw having all conflicting items stored
   dbContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
}
catch (ChangeConflictException ex)
{
   foreach (ObjectChangeConflict o in dbContext.ChangeConflicts)
     o.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges); // Resolve the conflicts, not just
                                         // refresh the context
   dbContext.SubmitChanges(); // and submit again
}
```